# Django DB insert incorrect string value

Tags: django, string, insert, models

I am parsing a csv file (created in windows) and trying to populate a database table using a model i've created.

I am getting this error:

```
pl = PriceList.objects.create(code=row[0], description=row[1],.........
Incorrect string value: '\xD0h:NAT...' for column 'description' at row 1
```

My table and the description field use utf-8 and utf8_general_ci collation.
The actual value i am trying to insert is this.

```
HOUSING:PS-187:1g\xd0h:NATURAL CO
```

I am not aware of any string processing i should do to get over this error.
I think i used a simple python script before to populate the database using conn.escape_string() and it worked (if that helps)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble with the CSV reader and unicode before as well.  In my case using the following got me past the errors.

From http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

> **The csv module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode,** ...
>
> unicode_csv_reader() below is a
>   generator that wraps csv.reader to
>   handle Unicode CSV data (a list of
>   Unicode strings). utf_8_encoder() is a
>   generator that encodes the Unicode
>   strings as UTF-8, one string (or row)
>   at a time. The encoded strings are
>   parsed by the CSV reader, and
>   unicode_csv_reader() decodes the
>   UTF-8-encoded cells back into Unicode:

```
import csv

def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    # csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                            dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        yield line.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: I don't want to read the entire file and pass it on to a function since the file contains 125k lines. Also, 'HOUSING:PS-187:1g\xd0h:NATURAL CO'.encode('utf-8') results in: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: This doesn't read the entire file, it wraps the CSV reader and you interact with the unicode_csv_reader as you would csv_reader.  It sounds like you've got a python-data encoding problem, not a Django problem.

Comment: Is there any way i can sanitize input so i can get around this problem?